# Get memcache data from php in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

I have problem with get data from memcache in nodejs.
First of all i set data in memcache with php
**Php code:**

```
$memcache = new Memcache;<br>
  $memcache->connect("localhost",11211);<br>
  $array = array("id"=>"1","name"=>"aaa");<br>
  $memcache->set("key",$array);
```

After this i check if this data is set in memcache and it show:
*a:2:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:3:"aa a";}*
Everything seems to be okay. Now i want to get this data in nodejs: 
**Nodejs code:**

```
var memcache = require('mem');
var client = new memcache.Client(11211,'localhost');
client.connect();
client.get('key', function(err,result){ 
console.log(result);
});
```

And here i have problem...In console i get

```
a:2:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:3:"aa a";}
```

And my **Question** is 
How to get in console name : aaa ?
I only add that:

```
console.log(result['name']); => show : undefined
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a more portable format to share data between the systems. E.g. JSON.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect("localhost",11211);
$data = json_encode(array("id"=>"1","name"=>"aaa"));
$memcache->set("key",$data);
```

I expect this to then show in memcache as

```
{ "id" : 1, "name": "aaa" }
```

Then you should be able to extract it as JSON:

```
var memcache = require('mem');
var client = new memcache.Client(11211,'localhost');
client.connect();
client.get('key', function(err,result){ 
    console.log(result);
    var entry = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(entry.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP data looks likes it's being automatically serialized for you.

Instead of letting that happen, I would suggest you encode your array into JSON data prior to inserting into memcache, which you can easily decode with node.

So instead of

```
$memcache->set("key",$array);
```

do:

```
$memcache->set("key", json_encode($array));
```

And then in node, instead of:

```
client.get('key', function(err,result){ 
    console.log(result);
});
```

do:

```
client.get('key', function(err,result){ 
    var object = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(object);
    console.log(object['name']);
});
```

Which will load that data into a JS object.